# More robust macro for ranges AND series of lines, measures, etc

Tags: macros, expl3, xparse

Starting with @egreg's marvellous `xparse` answer to my question about a  [Macro for abbreviated ranges (pages, music measures)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/212780/macro-for-abbreviated-ranges-pages-music-measures),

how to define a similar command that can also handle non-contiguous citations (both ranges and series)?

A fantasy version of this command would take input like `\range{\measures}{3-4,7,+9-11}` and expand to `mm.~3--4, 7, and 9--1`. This would depend on settings for the use of the serial comma and language for the conjunction (if `+` is input).

Here is the starting point from @egreg:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\range}{ m >{\SplitArgument{1}{ }}m }
 {%
  \dorange{#1}#2%
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\dorange}{ m m m }
 {%
  \IfNoValueTF{#3}{#1~#2}{#1[]~#2--#3}%
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\defineabbreviation}{ m m m }
 {%
  \NewDocumentCommand{#1}{o}{\IfNoValueTF{##1}{#2}{#3}}%
 }

\defineabbreviation{\lines}{l.}{ll.}
\defineabbreviation{\measures}{m.}{mm.}

\begin{document}

\range{\lines}{1}

\range{\lines}{2 3}

\range{\measures}{4}

\range{\measures}{5 6}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A macro that supports complex ranges must use the full force of `expl3`. Here's a possible solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\range}{ m m }
 {
  \cashner_range:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\tl_new:N \l__cashner_range_input_tl
\seq_new:N \l__cashner_range_input_seq
\bool_new:N \l__cashner_range_multi_bool

\cs_new_protected:Npn \cashner_range:nn #1 #2
 {
  % store the second argument in a token list
  \tl_set:Nn \l__cashner_range_input_tl { #2 }
  % change all -- into -
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l__cashner_range_input_tl { -- } { - }
  % change all - into -- (so as to normalize them)
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l__cashner_range_input_tl { - } { -- }
  % split the input at spaces (or whatever the second argument tells
  \seq_set_split:NnV \l__cashner_range_input_seq { ~ } \l__cashner_range_input_tl
  % set the “multi” boolean to false
  \bool_set_false:N \l__cashner_range_multi_bool
  \int_compare:nTF { \seq_count:N \l__cashner_range_input_seq == 1 }
   {% if the sequence has just one item check if `-` is in the input
    % and, in this case, set the boolean to true
    \tl_if_in:nnT { #2 } { - } { \bool_set_true:N \l__cashner_range_multi_bool }
   }
   {% more than one item, set the boolean to true
    \bool_set_true:N \l__cashner_range_multi_bool
   }
  % if the boolean is true, use the plural version of the abbreviation
  \bool_if:NTF \l__cashner_range_multi_bool
   { #1{p} } { #1{s} }\nobreakspace
   % use the sequence (with "and" between just two items,
   % a comma between all items except the last one
   % with ", and" between the last two, if more than two)
   \seq_use:Nnnn \l__cashner_range_input_seq { ~and~ } { ,~ } { ,~and\nobreakspace }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_set_split:Nnn { NnV }

\NewDocumentCommand{\defineabbreviation}{ m m m }
 {% define #1 to produce the singular version if the argument
  % is p, or singular if the argument is s
  \cs_new_protected:Npn #1 ##1
   {
    \str_case:nn{##1}{{s}{#2}{p}{#3}}
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\defineabbreviation{\lines}{l.}{ll.}

\begin{document}

\range{\lines}{1}

\range{\lines}{1-2}

\range{\lines}{1 3}

\range{\lines}{1--2 3 4}

\range{\lines}{1 2 3-5}

\end{document}
```

Note that you can input ranges as `1--2` or `1-2`, so it doesn't matter if your finger slips (but `1---2` would do no good).

The input is first stored in a token list, where `--` is normalized to `-` and `-` is normalized back to `--`, so at the end ranges will have `--`, independently on the input. After this preliminary step, the input is split at spaces into a sequence.

A boolean is set to true if either the sequence has more than one element or the unique element contains a hyphen. If the boolean is true, the macro in the first argument is called with the argument `p`, otherwise with `s`. Such macro should be defined through `\defineabbreviation` and not used elsewhere, unless you add the suitable argument (so `\lines{p}` is legal and will produce `ll.\nobreakspace`).

After printing the abbreviation (in singular or plural form), the sequence is used.

[image]

If you prefer a syntax such as

```
\range{\lines}{1-2,3, 4}
```

it's just a matter of changing the line

```
  \seq_set_split:NnV \l__cashner_range_input_seq { ~ } \l__cashner_range_input_tl
```

into

```
  \seq_set_split:NnV \l__cashner_range_input_seq { , } \l__cashner_range_input_tl
```

---

What if we want to provide localizations for `babel`? Here it is.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian,english]{babel}

\usepackage{xparse}


\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\range}{ m m }
 {
  \cashner_range:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\tl_new:N \l__cashner_range_input_tl
\tl_new:N \l_cashner_range_sep_two_tl
\tl_new:N \l_cashner_range_sep_many_tl
\tl_new:N \l_cashner_range_sep_last_tl
\seq_new:N \l__cashner_range_input_seq
\bool_new:N \l__cashner_range_multi_bool

\cs_new_protected:Npn \cashner_range:nn #1 #2
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l__cashner_range_input_tl { #2 }
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l__cashner_range_input_tl { -- } { - }
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l__cashner_range_input_tl { - } { -- }
  \bool_set_false:N \l__cashner_range_multi_bool
  \seq_set_split:NnV \l__cashner_range_input_seq { ~ } \l__cashner_range_input_tl
  \int_compare:nTF { \seq_count:N \l__cashner_range_input_seq == 1 }
   {
    \tl_if_in:nnT { #2 } { - } { \bool_set_true:N \l__cashner_range_multi_bool }
   }
   {
    \bool_set_true:N \l__cashner_range_multi_bool
   }
  \bool_if:NTF \l__cashner_range_multi_bool
   { #1{p} } { #1{s} }\nobreakspace
   \seq_use:NVVV \l__cashner_range_input_seq
    \l_cashner_range_sep_two_tl
    \l_cashner_range_sep_many_tl
    \l_cashner_range_sep_last_tl
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_set_split:Nnn { NnV }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_use:Nnnn { NVVV }

\NewDocumentCommand{\defineabbreviation}{ o m m m }
 {
  \IfNoValueTF { #1 }
   {
    \cs_new_protected:Npn #2 ##1
     {
      \str_case:nn{##1}{{s}{#3}{p}{#4}}
     }
   }
   {
    \exp_args:Nc \addto { extras#1 }
     {
      \cs_set_protected:Npn #2 ##1
       {
        \str_case:nn{##1}{{s}{#3}{p}{#4}}
       }
     }
   }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\setrangeseparators}{ommm}
 {
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}
   {
    \tl_set:Nn \l_cashner_range_sep_two_tl  { #2 }
    \tl_set:Nn \l_cashner_range_sep_many_tl { #3 }
    \tl_set:Nn \l_cashner_range_sep_last_tl { #4 }
   }
   {
    \exp_args:Nc \addto { extras#1 }
     {
      \tl_set:Nn \l_cashner_range_sep_two_tl  { #2 }
      \tl_set:Nn \l_cashner_range_sep_many_tl { #3 }
      \tl_set:Nn \l_cashner_range_sep_last_tl { #4 }
     }
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

% no argument means the default language

\setrangeseparators{ and }{, }{, and~}
\setrangeseparators[italian]{ e }{, }{ e~}%

\defineabbreviation{\lines}{l.}{ll.}
\defineabbreviation[italian]{\lines}{r.}{rr.}%


\begin{document}

\range{\lines}{1}

\range{\lines}{1-2}

\range{\lines}{1 3}

\range{\lines}{1--2 3 4}

\range{\lines}{1 2 3-5}

\selectlanguage{italian}

\range{\lines}{1}

\range{\lines}{1-2}

\range{\lines}{1 3}

\range{\lines}{1--2 3 4}

\range{\lines}{1 2 3-5}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Just to point out: the *fantasy version* does not split the argument at spaces (`~`) but commas :)

Comment: @Manuel Just change `~` in `\set_seq_split:NnV` to `,`

Comment: It was just in case someone didn't know.

Comment: @egreg I am using this immediately. Thank you. @Manuel Yes, I prefer the syntax with commas and will use that version: `\range{\measures}{3-4,5,7-9}`. Now, understanding the syntax will take me some time.

Comment: @egreg I like the "and" but someone else using this might want it to be optional or in another language. How much refactoring would that require?

Comment: @AndrewCashner Not really much. I can add a suitable version customizable for `babel`.